# Delaying a loop in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I've wrote the following function that is going to email each user when a post is published. It works just fine but the issue I'm having is that it can take a little while to publish the post due to the number of times it needs to run through the while loop. At the moment there are 110 members.

Now for my question, is there an easy way to delay this process so that the post can publish then the email sending functionality is taken care of in the background as a task?

```
function send_email_notifications() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'members',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => 0,
        'post_status' => array('pending', 'draft', 'publish'),
    );

    $emailSearch = new WP_Query($args);

    if(isset($_REQUEST['send_email_notification'])) {
        if($emailSearch->have_posts()) {
            while($emailSearch->have_posts()) {
                $emailSearch->the_post();

                wp_mail('test@test.com', 'Test', 'Test');
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('publish_notifications', 'send_email_notifications', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Sure. A "job scheduler" is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find WordPress Cron useful. In your `publish_notifications()` function you could have:

```
$args['subject'] = //something
$args['message'] = //something else
$args['to']      = //an email address

wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 3600, 'email_about_post', $args);
```

Then somewhere else you could have something like:

```
function email_about_post_function($args) {
    wp_mail($args['to'], $args['subject'], $args['message']);
}
add_action( 'email_about_post','email_about_post_function' );
```

Warning - I didn't test this particular code. Read more at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Comment: Thanks for the direction, James. Looked into the wp_schedule_single_event function further and I think that's just what I'm looking for.